# How can I get Vorbis libraries on Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ogg, oggvorbis, vorbis

OK, i've spent most of the day trying to do this, and I figure I've got to be missing something fairly obvious.

Vorbis files are apparently natively supported on the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html). Is there any way to access these libraries as a developer.

Situation: I've got a project that uses the [libvorbis and libogg libraries](http://xiph.org/downloads/), to load an ogg file. The whole thing compiles and works fine on OSX, linux, iOS etc. and i was trying to port it to android.

Using the NDK to compile the project, i get the error:
        `fatal error: vorbis/codec.h: No such file or directory`
        `compilation terminated.`
(I assume it would carry on to say that it can't find vorbisfile.h)

Question 1: Can access the vorbis API in C on Android? Or indeed, is there any Vorbis API?

Without too much effort, i stumbled across Tremor and [Tremolo](http://wss.co.uk/pinknoise/tremolo/) - ARM vorbis libraries, but I can't find any information on how to get them to compile using the Android SDK.

Question 2: Can someone offer any help with this?

Let me know if i can provide any other information to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might look at android/ffmpeg/x264 [project](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg) as an example. x264 is not ogg/vorbis, but it is a clear example of linking ffmpeg with adjunct libs in android build and link scenario.

Note: this will take quite a bit of time to work thru.

If you understand the example of building with x264, then you should be able to swap in obb/vorbis libs in place of x264 and get it all to link on an android build.

This assumes you are good with the NDK and cross toolchains and with git projects and sub-modules (x264 , ogg, vorbis)

Comment: x264 may be a dependency of ogg/vorbis.   Not sure about that

Comment: yep - it looks like jhotovy's fork has added the libogg and libvorbis libraries, and has some configure + make scripts! that's exactly what i needed. thanks, robert!

Answer (score -2):

maybe you can use the vorbis-java-1.0.0-beta of Xiph.org, this is a java package, you can port it to Android.